# "cat" bit-stream with no EOF

Tags: bash

I have a file opened both for reading and writing and associated this file with file descriptor `3`, i.e. `exec 3<>/dev/udp/10.10.10.1/161`. When I redirect a crafted UDP packet to file descriptor `3` and receive a reply, then how can I read it from file-descriptor `3`? Usual tools like `cat` or `read` do not work well as UDP packet(essentially just a bit stream) received as a reply does not have a newline or EOF and for example `cat` does not know that there is no more data to expect. For example here you can see how I had to `SIGINT` the cat:

```
$ cat <&3 
0Gpublic�:�0,0+C1841.local^C
$
```

I would like to check if there was any UDP data received from 10.10.10.1 and this means that if file-descriptor `3` contains some data(even a single bit), then reply was received.

Comment: Have you tried `head -c1` instead of `cat`?

Comment: @Felix Frank `head -c1` works fine as long as there is data in file. In case of no data(for example if UDP reply was not received), `head` will wait for input. This could be solved if `head` had a similar timeout(`-t`) option like `read` has..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot recognize an end-of-packet properly.  There is not EOF (as you noticed) signifier (like a special character or file-closed event or similar).  Instead all you can do is either

- read a fixed size of characters (in case your packets are fixed in size) or
- read single tokens (maybe bytes) until your packet's syntax states that it is complete or
- read until a timeout occurred.

The first two are up to your responsibility, in case this is possible.

The last one can be achieved using a `cat` in a subshell which you kill after a certain amount of time:

```
cat <&3 & pid=$!
sleep 0.1
kill "$pid" 2>/dev/null
```

Put this in a function and each call will last one 0.1s and output what could be read in that time.

Comment: thank you for explanation! I finally went with `read -n 1 -t 2 <&3`. In case there is at least some data in file `read` will exit with 0 and in case the file is empty, the `read` will timeout after two seconds and have a non-zero exit code.